# Designing a WLan Receiver

Tags: networking, matlab, simulink, wifi

I plan to model a Complete WLAN receiver for IEEE 802.11  b/g/n PHY Layer for completely detecting all the fields in the Packet.

This experiment is for academic purpose only. I am seeking your guidance, how I can build such a model.

Any ideas / pointers for designing such a receiver would be highly helpful for my studies.

Looking forward to hear some interesting ideas.

Thanks

Kiran

Answer (score 2):

With the new 802.11 framework in Linux you can just put an interface into monitor mode, and then capture frames with libpcap.  No need for special hacks.  Actually you don't even need any programming skills for some experimentation: just put your wlan0 into monitor mode, and start sniffing around with tcpdump.

Comment: Sorry.. I realized I am a registered User.. :) Anyway.. Its me again who asked t question.. The receiver is part of a bigger project. I plan to implement the WLAN receiver in a dedicated hardware ( FPGA ). Any idea in this direction, would be of great help.

Comment: Hardware is not any of my strong skills, but I guess you still plan to use some kind of COTS radio card, don't you?  What is the FPGA for?  Why don't you just use some embedded MIPS/PPC board with Linux?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion, But I plan to use the USRP (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Software_Radio_Peripheral)  to develop the Receiver.

Comment: I see.  But in this case, software/driver is provided for USRP with source code to integrate it with GNU radio.  The latter contains more or less all the software components you need for a 802.11 PHY implementation.  However, note this from the GNU radio FAQ: http://gnuradio.org/redmine/wiki/gnuradio/FAQ#Can-I-run-80211abgn-with-a-USRP  Developing your own hardware is also a tedious task, so you might need a backup plan if it doesn't work out.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I will keep this in mind. Meanwhile, I have to understand how to design the filter and all the signal processing related to the WLAN PHY signaling.